# Unable to return IEnumerable<TEnum> in place of IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, covariance

I wrote this EnumHelper method

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<TEnum, T>(Func<TEnum, T> projection = null) where TEnum : struct
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Type parameter TEnum must be an enum");

        if (projection == null)
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum)).OfType<TEnum>();

        return Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum)).OfType<TEnum>().Select(projection);
    }
```

I get a compile time error in the first return. That returns an `IEnumerable<TEnum>`

Error  46  Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEnum>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`

I don't have any constraints on `T`, so `T` is more generic than `TEnum`. In `IEnumerable<out T>` `T` is convariant, so why do I still get the error?

Comment: Covariance does not apply here; how does the compiler know anything about the relationship between `T` and `TEnum`? (it doesn't)

Comment: Also covariance is not supported by value types in C#. "where TEnum : struct"

Comment: @Mark because T could be anything since I don't have constraints to it, therefore you should be able to return anything in place of T

Comment: Imagine T is MemoryStream and TEnum is your enum type. Wow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Covariance only applies if there is a polymorphic relationship between the two types. In your case, `TEnum` and `T` are not constrained to be related, so covariance does not apply.

You could trivially fix this issue by casting your enumeration members directly to your target type:

```
if (projection == null)
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<T>();
```

**Edit**: I would suggest eliminating the `projection` parameter, and define your method more simply like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEnum> AsEnumerable<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Type parameter TEnum must be an enum");

    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<TEnum>();
}
```

If you do need to perform a projection, you could use the standard LINQ `Select` operation on the returned sequence:

```
var optionsA = AsEnumerable<RegexOptions>();
var optionsB = AsEnumerable<RegexOptions>().Select(o => o.ToString());
```

This will give you practically the same conciseness as your code, but save you the trouble of maintaining the optional parameter.

**Edit<sub>2</sub>**: If you really want to define an overload for the projection, I would suggest implementing all the logic within it, and then call it using the identity function from the parameterless version:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEnum> AsEnumerable<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct
{
    return AsEnumerable<TEnum, TEnum>(e => e);
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> AsEnumerable<TEnum, TResult>(
    Func<TEnum, TResult> projection) where TEnum : struct
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Type parameter TEnum must be an enum");

    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<TEnum>().Select(projection);
}
```

Sample calls:

```
var optionsA = AsEnumerable<RegexOptions>();
var optionsB = AsEnumerable<RegexOptions, string>(o => o.ToString());
```

Comment: @Douglas, Thanks for the reply. That's what I thought as well, but I wrote an overload for the projection